# Spread and join list of lists of unequal sizes with dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr, spread

I am interested in doing a fairly complicated join and I have not been able to find the answer. Here is an example dataset:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(age = c(2,2), id = c("T1", "T2"), Height = c(1.1,1.2), Number = c(1,1), node_age = c(0, 0))
dat3 <- data.frame(age = c(3,3,3,3), id = c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T2"), Height = c(1.1,2.2, 1.2, 2.3), Number = c(1,2,1,2), node_age = c(1,0,1,0))
dat4 <- data.frame(age = c(4,4,4,4,4,4), id = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2"), Height = c(1.1,2.2,3.3,1.2, 2.3,3.4 ), Number = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), node_age = c(2,1,0,2,1,0))
dat_list <- list(dat2, dat3, dat4)
```

I would like to take this list and join everything together, so that the outcome would look something like this:

```
$`T1`
  id Height Number_2 node_age_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Number_4 node_age_4
1 T1    1.1        1          0        1          1        1          2
2 T1    2.2       NA         NA        2          0        2          1
3 T1    3.3       NA         NA       NA         NA        3          0

$T2
  id Height Number_2 node_age_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Number_4 node_age_4
4 T2    1.2        1          0        1          1        1          2
5 T2    2.3       NA         NA        2          0        2          1
6 T2    3.4       NA         NA       NA         NA        3          0
```

Where the output is a list of lists by id and "Number" and "node_age" are repeated as functions of "age".

I have made some progress with gather, unite and spread. But I feel that it is inefficient to bind_rows of the list, then spread, then combine back into the list. Maybe I am wrong here?

My true data is a large list (115 elements). When I bind_rows of my list, I end up with 233561 observations. So I have many id's and node_age goes until 115, which is why I am aiming for list structures.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could bind the rows, then `split` by 'id' and `dcast` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
dat_list %>%
   bind_rows %>% 
   split(.$id) %>% 
   map(~  dcast(as.data.table(.x), id + Height ~ age, 
              value.var = c( 'Number', 'node_age')))
#$T1
#   id Height Number_2 Number_3 Number_4 node_age_2 node_age_3 node_age_4
#1: T1    1.1        1        1        1          0          1          2
#2: T1    2.2       NA        2        2         NA          0          1
#3: T1    3.3       NA       NA        3         NA         NA          0

#$T2
#   id Height Number_2 Number_3 Number_4 node_age_2 node_age_3 node_age_4
#1: T2    1.2        1        1        1          0          1          2
#2: T2    2.3       NA        2        2         NA          0          1
#3: T2    3.4       NA       NA        3         NA         NA          0
```

---

Or we use `gather/spread` instead of `dcast`

```
dat_list %>% 
   bind_rows %>%
   split(.$id) %>%
   map(~ .x  %>% 
            gather(key, val, Number:node_age) %>%
            unite(keyage, key, age) %>%
            spread(keyage, val))
#$T1
#  id Height node_age_2 node_age_3 node_age_4 Number_2 Number_3 Number_4
#1 T1    1.1          0          1          2        1        1        1
#2 T1    2.2         NA          0          1       NA        2        2
#3 T1    3.3         NA         NA          0       NA       NA        3

#$T2
#  id Height node_age_2 node_age_3 node_age_4 Number_2 Number_3 Number_4
#1 T2    1.2          0          1          2        1        1        1
#2 T2    2.3         NA          0          1       NA        2        2
#3 T2    3.4         NA         NA          0       NA       NA        3
```

---

If we need the columns in a particular `order`, create the 'key' as a `factor` columns with `levels` specified in that order to change the `order` in `spread`

```
dat_list %>% 
    bind_rows %>%
    split(.$id) %>%
    map(~ .x  %>% 
             gather(key, val, Number:node_age) %>%
             group_by(key) %>%
             mutate(rn = row_number())  %>%
             ungroup %>% 
             arrange(rn) %>%
             unite(keyage, key, age) %>%
             mutate(keyage = factor(keyage, levels = unique(keyage))) %>% 
             select(-rn) %>%
             spread(keyage, val))
#$T1
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  id    Height Number_2 node_age_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Number_4 node_age_4
#  <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 T1       1.1        1          0        1          1        1          2
#2 T1       2.2       NA         NA        2          0        2          1
#3 T1       3.3       NA         NA       NA         NA        3          0

#$T2
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  id    Height Number_2 node_age_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Number_4 node_age_4
#  <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 T2       1.2        1          0        1          1        1          2
#2 T2       2.3       NA         NA        2          0        2          1
#3 T2       3.4       NA         NA       NA         NA        3          0
```

Comment: This is close but highlights some of the issues I ran into with gather / unite / spread originally. It is important for later analyses for the columns to be arranged as in the example above. For example, node_age_2, Number_2, node_age_3, Number_3 etc.

Comment: @user2325155  That is very easy to do with `order`

Comment: The default of `spread` is to arrange columns alphabetically, which is what we see here. Is there a way to call this without specifying `order` manually?

Comment: Thank you for the solution thus far. When applying the last chunk of code to my larger dataset, I run into the following: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows`. A solution to this is posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/spread-why-errors/2076) but that involves moving removing `rn` after `spread`, which causes errors when applying the spread across multiple heights. Any suggestions or is there a dcast solution to this? Many thanks.

Comment: @user2325155  You may need to create a sequence variable.

Comment: Figured it out. I added
        `group_by_at(vars(-val)) %>% 
        mutate(row_id=1:n()) %>% 
        ungroup %>% 
        spread(keyage, val) %>% 
        select(-row_id))`
after `select(-rn)`. Thanks for all the help!